# How can I overwrite specific values in an matrix? MATLAB

Tags: matlab

For a university assignment I have to take an image of size 512x512 and then apply an effect to particular blocks of the image, as displayed in the image below.

[image]

I have managed to achieve this by accessing particular regions of the image using indexing, like this:

`w1_region = [DCTImage(1:imageSizeQuarter, imageSizeQuarter+1:imageSizeHalf)];`

This is repeated for w2 and w3. These regions are all of size 128x128 and need to be written back into the original image.

However now what I need to do is overwrite the blocks of the original image with the edited blocks, so that I have a full image with 3 blocks `w1`, `w2`, `w3` that have been modified.

How can I go about overwriting the matrix that defines the original image with the modified blocks? Is there a way that I can effectively say "Overwrite the values held in the matrix starting at X"?

I feel like there is some kind of matrix operation that would allow me to do this but I'm not entirely sure which.

Comment: `DCTImage(1:imageSizeQuarter, imageSizeQuarter+1:imageSizeHalf) = modified_region1` ?

Comment: I tried this, I literally have `watermarkedDCTImage(1:imageSizeQuarter, imageSizeQuarter+1:imageSizeHalf) = w1_region;` in my code. But when I attempt to reconstruct the image using inverse DCT transform and then `figure, imshow()` the image just comes out white?

Comment: You need to normalize between 0 and 1. also make sure you have `double` and not `uint8` when you do the transformation.

Comment: I was forgetting to cast back to uint8 in order to view the image. Daft of me. Working now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example:

```
BlockFunc = @(block_struct) YourFunction(block_struct);
block_size = [128 128];
block_edges = blockproc(file_name,block_size,BlockFunc);
```

You should just create a function with Name of YourFunction. The input of this function is block_struct and you can access to your block position and its data.
Moreover you can use global variable to handle between YourFunction and your main script.